# Boot-Repair message on Ubuntu 22.04 on Asus Vivobook

Tags: boot, 22.04, boot-repair

After running Boot-Repair I got the following Boot Info Summary: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gFHBSm2Jtq/) .

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Intel Corporation from Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic root=UUID=29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p2 ext4  468G  238G  207G  54% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: X412FA.304(5.13) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2676221a-d075-46ac-a330-3bd4c52c8e31,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....@...............


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 12B6E710-3B4E-40EA-85EE-EABBB08B2E23
            Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:512GB:512GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     B595-A741                            2676221a-d075-46ac-a330-3bd4c52c8e31       EFI System Partition
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b c4e4fd60-1e3c-4014-bc8b-f8fbd32d6e9b       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2                      206.5G  51% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic   29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-57-generic   29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=29846492-b4f7-4129-9644-93e24a492f7b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=B595-A741  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 367,777999878 = 394,898620416  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 221,847671509 = 238,207123456  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 403,917980194 = 433,703628800  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-57-generic                 2
 221,847671509 = 238,207123456  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic                 2
 403,917980194 = 433,703628800  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 377,844722748 = 405,707681792  boot/initrd.img                                5
 399,844722748 = 429,330001920  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-57-generic              6
 377,844722748 = 405,707681792  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic              5
 399,844722748 = 429,330001920  boot/initrd.img.old                            6

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 apr 15  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 apr 15  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 apr 15  2022 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: So do you have an issue? Report looks normal, it is offering to reinstall grub which is a normal fix that it offers which fixes many boot issues.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems, it doesn't boot from where it should from, i.e. no automatic boot

Comment: Check that you have UEFI as first in boot order and make sure Ubuntu is the first entry in boot order in UEFI settings. You still show a Windows UEFI entry, but no Windows. See line 48 in report. So UEFI menu should show ubuntu as first choice. Some system want to boot Windows and are not happy if you do not have a Windows entry. What brand/model system? We can create an UEFI boot entry whose description is Windows, but boots grub or shim file. They only check description not actual boot file.

Comment: I saw this: Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) ! The only problem: I don't know, where to do this! Another question: why does this only appear since updating from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Comment: If you look at the UEFI section of report it shows the Ubuntu entry using shimx64.efi. Shim is used for UEFI Secure Boot, but also can be used for those with Secure boot off. So then the entry is not really grubx64.efi but shimx64.efi. But in your UEFI boot menu is may just show description or "ubuntu".

Comment: In the boot menu it shows ubuntu, not the version, but how do I get the UEFI firmware to boot on 22.04.1 LTS as indicated in the repair?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, it's an ASUS Vivobook X412FA, American Megatrends, Windows (10?) came pre-installed, but I never used it and booted to 20.04.LTS from USB and had no problems at all so far, until direct upgrade to 22.04 LTS, when the screen started freezing. I thought it were a problem with snap-Chromium and installed Chromium from a repository. It worked well for a time, then the screen started freezing again, less, but still freezing even with few tabs open.

Comment: I typically prefer clean install & restore from backup. Do you have latest firmware for UEFI and if SSD for that also? When you start system from cold/power totally down start up, press escape right after vendor logo to get grub menu. And then does recovery mode boot? And then several command line repair options.

Comment: Recovery mode boots, and normal boot also works, the crashes are disturbing when you are in a timed test and Chromium freezes or crashes all of a sudden, I will have to a new install then, although I hate set up all again, Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: If you have good backups, you should be able to reinstall & restore very quickly. But it sounds more like a hardware or driver issue. Do logs shown anything on what is crashing? Review log files
`sudo grep -Ei 'warn|error' /var/log/*g`

Comment: @oldfred thanks, re-install did the trick, but the error at startup is still the same, the rest running like a charm, my backups unfortunately weren't